Login to Garmin Connect using Selenium in Excel VBA
I want to pull data from my Garmin Connect account for analysis in Excel.
I'm using the following script (email and password replaced with generic words). It works until I get to the submit statement when I get

An unexpected error has occurred

on the webpage.

I can open a web browser manually and login with no issue.
Sub update()

Dim obj As New EdgeDriver

obj.Get "https://connect.garmin.com/"
obj.Wait 5000

obj.FindElementByXPath("//a[@href = '/signin']").Click
obj.Wait 5000

obj.FindElementById("email").SendKeys ("email@gmail.com")
obj.FindElementById("password").SendKeys ("password")
obj.FindElementByXPath("//button[@type ='submit']").Click


Instead of doing a click on the submit, Try to identify the form containing the credentials and then theForm.Submit
